# Remove mysql symlink as it points to nothing

Tags: mysql, macos, hyperlink, terminal, symlink

A long time ago when I installed mysql I symlinked the term mysql to /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql.

Recently I removed mysql completely and used homebrew to reinstall it. Now the term mysql supposedly points to nothing, which is fine, but I can't unlink it. Typing mysql into terminal returns

```
-bash: /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql: No such file or directory
```

and unlink mysql returns

```
unlink: mysql: No such file or directory
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out how to fix it - There was an alias set in my bash profile which is a hidden file located in my home folder, removing alias set in the that file finally worked.

Comment: This fixed it for me too. In my case, the line in ~/.bash_profile that I had to remove was this: `export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin/:${PATH}`